# C#.net could't Insert record in to ms access database

Tags: c#

When I trying to insert the record on ms access database.
I got the error I attached below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=E:/school.accdb;");
OdbcCommand cmd;

string name,course,fee;
name = txtname.Text;
course = txtcourse.Text;
fee = txtfee.Text;

sql = "insert into record(name,course,fee)values(?,?,?)";           
cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, con);
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("course", course);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fee", fee);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record adddedddd");
txtname.Clear();
txtcourse.Clear();
txtfee.Clear();
txtname.Focus();

con.Close();
```

Comment: First thing to check is your Data Source... is it actually where you say it is `E:/school.accdb` - and does your "slash" direction affect the path...

Comment: so how to write this sir

Comment: You are using the OleDb driver but you are trying to create an OdbcConnection. Change every "Odbc" to "Ole" and your code should run

Comment: thanks alot sir workinggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the things together that were said in the comments (thanks to @Fenton and @Steve):

```
string name = txtname.Text;
string course = txtcourse.Text;
string fee = txtfee.Text;
string sql = "insert into record(name,course,fee) values(?,?,?)";

using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=E:\school.accdb;")) {
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("course", course);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fee", fee);

    con.Open();
    int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show($"{n} Record adddedddd");
}
txtname.Clear();
txtcourse.Clear();
txtfee.Clear();
txtname.Focus();
```

I also enclosed the connection object in a `using` statement to make sure the connection gets closed and disposed.

Note that I used a verbatim string `@"..."` for the connection string. This allows me to use the backslash for the path. Otherwise C# interpretes the backslash as escape.

See: [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)